# Prove that the product of five consecutive integers is divisible by $5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I started out by writing $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$. I know I have to use induction after distributing this product but to me it seems inefficient because of the heavy calculation. Is there a better way to approach this proof?

Comment: Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: you indicated how you started, but not how you finished. So you do not have a proof. A more efficient way to not have a proof is to not start it at all. If you did have some proof then it would make sense to ask if there was a way to improve it, and make it more efficient. Given you have not provided a proof, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the algebra easier, let $m=n+2.$  The product is then

$(m-2)(m-1)m(m+1)(m+2)=(m-2)(m+2)(m-1)(m+1)m$

$=(m^2-4)(m^2-1)m=(m^4-5m^2+4)m=m^5-5m^3+4m.  $

By Fermat's little theorem, $m^5\equiv m\pmod 5.$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

The only way the product is divisible by $5$ is if [at least] one of the five integers is divisible by $5$. Can you show this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $\Bbb Z_5$ has order $5$.  But, each of $[n+k]\,,0\le k\le4$ represents a different element of $\Bbb Z_5$ (proof?).  $\therefore $ one of them is $[0]$.

Answer (score 1):

Any integer must be of the form $5k, 5k+1, 5k+2, 5k+3, 5k+4$ for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$. Since these numbers are consecutive, they are all of a different form, so we always have one of each form. Therefore...

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Note that $a_{k+1}=a_k+5(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)$.

$a_{k+1}$ is divisible by $5$  if and only if $a_k$  is divisible by $5$

As $a_1=(1)(1+1)(1+2)(1+3)(1+4)$ is divisible by $5$, by induction, $a_n$ is divisible by $5$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (both positive and negative).

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of Euclid's Division lemma? It states that any positive integer can be represented in the form a=bq+r.
Where b>r>=0.
Now let's take for this case, b = 5
Now a= 5q or 5q+ 1 or 5q+2 or 5q+3 or 5q+4.
Take five cases, in each k = anyone of these. And show that in each case, the product is divisible by 5. And then conclude that since in each possible case , the product is 5, therefore the statement must be true.